# updating data in html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

i work as a content editor of 4 websites on a content management system of a university(very old and slow system).
the problem is i have no access to the databases so i need to write everything inside the html and everytime i need to update the news of the website i have to do it manually through the html.

is there any thing i can do to make staff a littlebit organized 
for example storing the news in seperate file 
and the website will take the data from that file. 
can i do that using javascript or php(i have access to the php) or a framework for them.
do i need to pay for sql database outside and link it or what?
what do you suggest guys?

Comment: PHP require function can be used to pull in plain text or HTML.

Comment: Have you considered storing your data in a XML or Json file instead of writing the html every time? (NOTE : this isn't super secure, but if you don't mind this it could be a better way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Basicly!!!
your old html file

```
<div>last found news</div>
```

Now seperate: news_20150101.txt
"news from news 2015-01-01"

PHP (not HTML): news.php

```
<div><?php print file_get_contents('news_20150101.txt');?></div>
```

if load all files of the news folder do it like:

```
<?php foreach(scandir('newsfolder/') as $newsfile){ ?>
<div><?php printfile__get_contents($newsfile);?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

But that can be more komplexer if you want.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could save the news in a file and that load that file from the websites that need to show it.

   - Make a page where you will put the news which will write to a file. [How to? - link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp). (probably you would need to think about login and other security concerns so other ).
   - Include the file(in which you are writing the news) in the websites that show the news. [How to? - link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp).
2. You could store the data in a mysql db (mysql is free but you would need a host where you can have your database settled).

   - Find a host where you can save your mysql database(when settling with the host provider, you will want to check if they allow you to access the database remotely and not only locally)
   - Create the database on your host
   - After you have the database settled, you will know the domain and necessary credentials that you will need to access it via php
   - From all the websites, include a php file where you access your database and load the news (putting all the functionality about loading the news in a separate file would be better because you don't implement the same functionality in all the websites)

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `require` function can be used to pull in plain text and html from a file on the server. For example, if you have 2 files, assuming in the same directory:

main.php:

```
<?php

echo "<p>Header goes here.</p>";

require 'content.html';

echo "<p>Footer goes here.</p>";

?>
```

content.html:

```
<p>Plain old HTML</p>
```

Output when main.php is loaded in a browser:

---

Header goes here.

Plain old HTML

Footer goes here.

---

Alternatively main.php can look like:

```
<p>Header goes here.</p>

<?php require 'content.html'; ?>

<p>Footer goes here.</p>
```